# Javascript search array of lists of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items I need to loop thru. I need to search if an array of items contains an array of items. This is the array, first value is timestamp, second is a count:

```
const i = [
    [1614719782079, 1],
    [1614719782085, 1],
    [1614719782091, 2],
    [1614719782096, 2],
]
```

And I have a forEach loop that goes thru all this data from my backend and I need to check if the timestamp exists in the array(the first value) and if it does, add to the second value of the array(count). This is an example data from backend:

```
  const mockData = [
    {
      ...someData,
      details: {
        eventTimestamp: 1614719782079, 
        equipmentId: 5,
        otherUselessData...
      }
    },
    {
      ...someData,
      details: {
        eventTimestamp: 1614719782079, 
        equipmentId: 5,
        otherUselessData...
      }
    }
  ]
```

Basically if `eventTimestamp` in the mockData exists in the `i`, then increment the second value in that array. PS dont ask about the horrible structure of the this data lol. This is all I have to work with

Comment: Can Someone help me a bit further...something changed and I need to store the  timestamps in i to be in 30minute intervals in the last 24hours. And instead of checking if the timestamps are equal, I need to check if the timestamp is within the 2 timestamp intervals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code should do the trick:

```
mockData.forEach(mock => {
  const el = i.find(e => e[0] === mock.details.eventTimestamp);
  if(el) {
    el[1]++
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

1. Create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the elements of `i` where the first item is the `key` and the second is the `value`
2. Iterate over `mockData`, and in each iteration, if the `eventTimestamp` is in this map, increment its `value`
3. In the end, update `i` to the `entries` of this map

```js
let i = [
    [1614719782079, 1],
    [1614719782085, 1],
    [1614719782091, 2],
    [1614719782096, 2],
];
const mockData = [
    { details: { eventTimestamp: 1614719782079, equipmentId: 5 } },
    { details: { eventTimestamp: 1614719782079, equipmentId: 5 } }
];

const updateTimestampCounts = (arr=[]) => {
  const map = new Map();
  i.forEach(([ timestamp, count ]) => map.set(timestamp, count));

  arr.forEach(({ details={} }) => {
    const { eventTimestamp } = details;
    const count = map.get(eventTimestamp);
    if(count) map.set(eventTimestamp, count+1);
  });
  
  i = [...map.entries()];
}

updateTimestampCounts(mockData)
console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my edited solution, sorry , didnt understand it in first time

```js
const i = [
    [1614719782079, 1],
    [1614719782085, 1],
    [1614719782091, 2],
    [1614719782096, 2],
]

const mockData = [
    {
      details: {
        eventTimestamp: 1614719782079, 
        equipmentId: 5,
      }
    },
    {
      details: {
        eventTimestamp: 1614719782079, 
        equipmentId: 5,
        count: 1,
      }
    }
  ]
  
mockData.forEach(mock => {
  const el = i.find(e => e[0] === mock.details.eventTimestamp);
  if(el) {
    el[1]++
  }
})
  console.log(i)
```